# Mediaplayer finalized without being released (JNI)

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I m getting a warning  message in logcat

> W/MediaPlayer-JNI(16795): MediaPlayer finalized without being released

Please tell me where i m wrong and how to resolve the problem.
I want when playAudio is called second time then it stops previous mMediaPlayer audio playbacks.

```
public class WordAudio  {

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
String url;
private static WordAudio wordAudio;
private WordAudio() {
}

public static WordAudio getInstance() {
    if (wordAudio == null) {
        wordAudio = new WordAudio();
    }
    return wordAudio;

}

public void playAudio(final Context context, String id) {

    try {

        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }           
        }

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        url = AUDIO_STREEM_URL+"id=" + id+ "&x=mp3";
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(url)); 
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer) {    
                //mMediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });


        mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {                       
                } else if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) {
                   mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Thanks

Comment: just guess `//mMediaPlayer.release();`

Comment: Are u asking me to remove the comment of mMediaPlayer.release();

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting.

Comment: Thanks but then i started getting  V/MediaPlayer(15255): callback application
 V/MediaPlayer(15255): back from callback
 E/MediaPlayer(15255): mOnBufferingUpdateListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE message.
 V/MediaPlayer(15255): message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
 V/MediaPlayer(15255): buffering 100

Comment: I would move all of your mediaplayer initializing to a different method so that it can be setup again easily on subsequent calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done this way

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
url = AUDIO_STREEM_URL;
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(url)); 
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer) {    
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: For Me Still Dose Not Work !

Comment: ask it as a new questoin